# New to Java: Is there a better way to write this simple code

Tags: java

```
private void addMember() {
    while (true) {
        String mNum = readLine("Please enter a membership number: ");
        if (mNum == null) break;
        Integer mNumAsInteger = Integer.parseInt(mNum);
        String mName = readLine("Please enter the member's name: ");
        members.put(mNumAsInteger, mName);
    }
}

private Map<Integer, String> members = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

The purpose of the code is to keep adding members until user enter a blank input.

Is there a way to change the first line to something like

```
Integer mNum = readInt("Please enter a membership number: ");
```

And somehow detects a blank input?

Comment: Try a/the code-review stack. There is no [standard] all-in-one function like that. Also, I would recommend using `int` unless there is a need for `Integer`.

Comment: Use scanner, or simply refactor the code into a utility method.

Comment: @pst

I thought I must to use Integer because HashMap only accept type Objects?

Comment: @user1296058 you're partially right, but [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) can take care of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), which provides a simpler API for reading from a stream.

```
private static void addMember() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter a membership number: ");
            int mNum = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter the member's name: ");
            String mName = sc.next();
            members.put(mNum, mName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/jhN3j

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the best, but maybe what you are looking for:

```
try{
Integer mNum = Integer.parseInt(readLine("Please enter a membership number: "));
}catch (NumberFormatException e){
 System.out.println("Error parsing membership number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try this class: http://www.cs.kzoo.edu/GridPkg/GridPkgClassDocumentation/edu/kzoo/util/ValidatedInputReader.html